# Where do I report an improper Wikipedia article?

Tags: wikipedia

There is an artwork in the entrance of my University campus. On that artwork, there was an apothegm which belongs to a certain historical artist. Recently the artwork has been restored; in the progress, they removed that apothegm.

A group students from the department of literature who are fans of that artist (the owner of the apothegm) got very angry with this situation. They created a Wikipedia article whose title is the apothegm.

In the beginning of the article (not in English) there are only two short sentences which tell about the meaning of the apothegm and give the name of its owner. The long rest of the article explains the story of how it was written on our campus entrance and how it got removed. It also includes formal criticism targeting the campus president for his decision.

I'm using Wikipedia for accessing information frequently and I'm contributing in it as much as I can. I am very disturbed about this misuse. What can I do about this issue. Do I report it somewhere, or do I add a special code in the page in order to mark it for moderator review?

Comment: There is a well-defined article deletion process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Deletion_process

Comment: You mention the article is not in English, so you should refer to the equivalent page in the appropriate language.

Comment: Each language version of Wikipedia has its own rules (though they are going to be similar in many respects). So, it would be helpful if you mentioned which Wikipedia do you mean. Is it Turkish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Al Everett said in a comment above, [Wikipedia makes no secret of the deletion process.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Deletion_process) There's a Wikipedia page, put out by Wikipedia, about it.

[image]